# How to use xsl:foreach to select variables form un-nested elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have typed up some XML of a cinema. I need to use XSLT transformations to output information from 'screen 1' into a table. The table should show the three screening times of 'screen 1' and what film it is playing, similar to the table below:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╗
║Showing Time║ Film        ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1:30pm     ║ The Revenant║
║ 5:00pm     ║ The Revenant║
║ 8:30pm     ║ The Revenant║
╚════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Here is my XML, although I don't know if it's been written in the best way for the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Assignment1.xsl"?>
<Cinema>
  <Name> Old Street Cinema</Name>
  <Address>23 Old Street, Oxford</Address>
  <Telephone>01865 123456</Telephone>
  <Owner>John Arbuttle</Owner>
  <Showings>
    <Showing>
      <Films>
        <Film>
          <Screen>1</Screen>
          <Name>The Revenant</Name>
          <Usher>Sarah Eccles</Usher>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <Screen>2</Screen>
          <Name>Zoolander 2</Name>
          <Usher>Ari Ventaro</Usher>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <Screen>3</Screen>
          <Name>Star Wars the Force Awakens</Name>
          <Usher>Jake Calcas</Usher>
        </Film>
      </Films>
    </Showing>
  </Showings>
  <ScreenTimes>
    <Time name="Afternoon">1:30pm</Time>
    <Time name="Early Evening">5:00pm</Time>
    <Time name="Late Evening">8:30pm</Time>
  </ScreenTimes>
</Cinema>
```

And here is the unfinished XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Cinema">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>The Old Street Cinema </h1>
        <h2>Screen 1</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Showing Time</th>
            <th>Film</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="ScreenTimes">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Time" /></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is: how can I use XSLT to put both the showing time and the name of the film in the table when the elements aren't nested together.

Comment: I fixed your XML to be _well-formed_, but I don't know if it's the form you expected. However, the XML still doesn't provide the necessary information to associate the movies with the playtime. So, so far this question is unsolvable unless you assume that the first playtime coincides with the first movie title listed.

Comment: I thought there would be a better way to code the XML by either nesting the three showings in each <Screen> element or vice versa but I still am unsure how to use XSLT to put the information into a table.

Comment: @Henrymcp How is the XSLT supposed to know which screen to pick? Will you be passing it as a parameter, or do you want to hard-code it into the stylesheet or ...?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is twofold:

- First possibility: Using the index of the playtime `Time` as an index to the movie title:

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Cinema">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>The Old Street Cinema </h1>
        <h2>Screen 1</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Showing Time</th>
            <th>Film</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="ScreenTimes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Time">
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/Cinema/Showings/Showing/Films/Film[$pos]/Name/text()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- Second possibility: Restructure your XML file to incorporate the playtime in your movie data so that the XML file looks like this:

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="a.xslt"?>
<Cinema>
  <Name> Old Street Cinema</Name>
  <Address>23 Old Street, Oxford</Address>
  <Telephone>01865 123456</Telephone>
  <Owner>John Arbuttle</Owner>
  <Showings>
    <Showing>
      <Films>
        <Film>
          <Screen>1</Screen>
          <Name>The Revenant</Name>
          <Usher>Sarah Eccles</Usher>
          <Playtime>Afternoon</Playtime>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <Screen>2</Screen>
          <Name>Zoolander 2</Name>
          <Usher>Ari Ventaro</Usher>
          <Playtime>Early Evening</Playtime>
        </Film>
        <Film>
          <Screen>3</Screen>
          <Name>Star Wars the Force Awakens</Name>
          <Usher>Jake Calcas</Usher>
          <Playtime>Late Evening</Playtime>
        </Film>
      </Films>
    </Showing>
  </Showings>
  <ScreenTimes>
    <Time name="Afternoon">1:30pm</Time>
    <Time name="Early Evening">5:00pm</Time>
    <Time name="Late Evening">8:30pm</Time>
  </ScreenTimes>
</Cinema>
```

and the XSLT file extracts the relevant data into the HTML table like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/Cinema">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>The Old Street Cinema </h1>
        <h2>Screen 1</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Showing Time</th>
            <th>Film</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="ScreenTimes">
    <xsl:for-each select="Time">
      <xsl:variable name="time" select="@name" />
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/Cinema/Showings/Showing/Films/Film[Playtime = $time]/Name" /></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is far from perfect, because most likely there is more than one movie per playtime. You'd have to 'invert' the `for-each` loop to achieve this - meaning iterating over the movies and associating the time. However, without more information I cannot give a better answer.

Comment: This looks much better but one thing I didn't clarify is that each screen has all 3 showing times. Also the table is only outputting the information from 'screen 1', meaning one film is repeated 3 times (See table in question)

Comment: @Henrymcp: Yes. It sounds a lot more sensible that each screen has its own set of movies. Please update your question with this information and the desired outcome. Proceeding on my answer it should be a piece of cake to satisfy your (not yet mentioned) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Cinema">
    <xsl:variable name="film" select="Showings/Showing/Films/Film[1]/Name" />
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>The Old Street Cinema </h1>
            <h2>Screen 1</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Showing Time</th>
                    <th>Film</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ScreenTimes/Time">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="$film" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your input, will return (shown as rendered):

[image]

**Note**:

- the screen # is hard-coded (as is your screen name);
- your XML could be simplified by removing the `Showing` and `Films` wrappers;
- your XML assumes screening times are identical for all screens.